# Значение и происхождение слова "аминь"

Tags: значение-слов, выбор-слов, этимология

Почему это слово используется в основном в религиозном контексте? Как правильно применять это слово и с какими выражениями сочетать?

Answer (score 3):

> Значение и происхождение слова “аминь”

Из *"Этимологического словаря современного русского языка" Шапошникова (М., 2010):*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Плюс см. ***["Полный церковнославянскій словарь" прот. Г. Дьяченко:](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0014.htm)***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, перенесите текст с изображения в тело ответа: к сожалению, оно может отображаться с ошибками.

Answer (score 1):

Правильное значение (и буквальный перевод) - "поистине", "верно". Но совершенно не "конец" или "всё кончено". С очень большой натяжкой можно использовать "аминь" в смысле "всё уже сказано" или "договорились". Причём, о вещах невесёлых или неприятных. Лучше уж в этом значении использовать выражение другого интересного народа: "Хау, я всё сказал!"

("Аминь" не должно употребляться как "кончено" т.к. по основному назначению - во время молитвы - может произноситься много раз, а не только и не обязательно в самом конце.)

Answer (score 1):

По Фасмеру, слово "аминь" происходит от древнерусского, старославянского ***аминъ***, древнегреческого ***ἀμήν*** «воистину» или от древнегреческого ***μήν*** «поистине, действительно, в самом деле», из иврита ***אמן*** «истинно, верно».